# Running MongoDB and Redis on two different containers in the same host machine

Tags: mongodb, redis, virtual-machine, docker, linux-containers

I have read somewhere that MongoDB and Redis server shouldn't be executed in the same host because the way that Redis manages the memory damages MongoDb. This is before Docker.io. But now thing seems are pretty different or not? Is is convenient running Redis server and MongoDB on two different containers on the same host machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker does not change your hardware, also it is the OS that deals with resources which is not virtualized so the same rules as a normal hardware should apply here.

**RAM**

MongoDB and Redis don't share any memory. The problem of using the same host will be that you can run out of RAM with these two processes, you can put a max size for redis, you can probably do the same for MongoDB, it is mandatory.

If your sizing is good (MongoDB RAM + Redis RAM < Hardware RAM), you won't get any swap on disk for redis (which is absolutely what you want to prevent) but maybe mongodb cache won't be as good (not enough place for optimization). Less memory for redis is always a challenge if your data grows: beware of out of memory if the data size is unpredictable!

If you use backups with redis, it uses more RAM than its dataset to produce the dump, so beware of that. It implies also using IO.

**IO**

In this case (less RAM) mongo will do a lot more of IO to access data. Redis, depending on your backup policy, can use IO or not (your choice). Worst case: if you use AOF on redis, it is a lot of IO so maybe IO can become a bottleneck in this architecture. If you don't use backups with redis: you won't have problems. Also a SSD is a good choice for Mongo.

**CPU**

I don't know if MongoDB uses a lot of CPU, but redis most of the time does not except during backups. If you use backups with redis: try to have two CPU cores available for it (one for redis, one for backup task).

**Network**

It depends on your number of clients. But you should check the throughput / input load of your machine to see if you are not saturating (using monit for instance with alerts). Sometimes it is the bottleneck, not enought throughput in one machine!

Answer (score 2):

Many of today's services, in particular Databases, are very aggressive consuming resources and are designed thinking they will (or should) be executed in a dedicated machine for them. MongoDB and Redis try to keep a lot of data in memory and will try to take the more memory they can for themselves. To avoid this services take all the memory of your host machine you can limit the maximum memory used by a container using `-m="<number><optional unit>"` in `docker run`. E.g.: `docker run -d -m="2g" -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb dockerfile/mongodb`

So you can control in an easy way the resource limits of your services, and run them in the same host with a fine grained control of the resources. Anyway it's important to consider that the performance of these services is designed thought that the resources of the host machine will be fully available for them. For example there are other databases as Cassandra that will consume a lot of memory, and furthermore, are designed to have sequential access writing to disk. In these cases Docker will let you to run limiting the resources used, but if you run multiple services in the same host the performance of them will decrease severely.